# How should I work around an ASP.Net MVC Route mapping conflict?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, routes, conflict

I have two routes mapped in my MVC application:

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Project",
        "{controller}/{projectid}/{action}/{id}",
        new { controller = "Project", action = "Index", id = "" });

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default",                                              // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
    );

}
```

For the most part, these pose no problems, but I do strike trouble when trying to call the /Account/LogOn view.  My ActionLink syntax looks like this (I've tried a couple of variations including null route values and such):

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("Log On", "LogOn", "Account") %>
```

Browsing to this view raises a 404 error ("The resource cannot be found").  Ideally I'd like to avoid a huge amount of rework, so what would be the best way to avoid these clashes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this variation with the literal for the controller?

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Project",
        "Project/{projectid}/{action}/{id}",
        new { controller = "Project", action = "Index", id = "" });

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default",                                              // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
    );
}
```

This would catch: http://localhost/Project/12 and http://localhost/Project/12/Edit and http://localhost/Project/2/View/2

But it would pass http://localhost/Account/LogOn to the second rounte. Yes?

Comment: Gaaa!  It's always the simplest and most obvious answers.  That's done it. Thanks.